# Checking for keyup event in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the [jQuery Credit Card Validator](http://jquerycreditcardvalidator.com/) to validate credit cards.

The basic usage is given as

```
$('#cc_number').validateCreditCard(function(result)
{
alert('CC type: ' + result.card_type.name
  + '\nLength validation: ' + result.length_valid
  + '\nLuhn validation: + result.luhn_valid');
});
```

I looked on the demo JS file included on that site and couldn't make head nor tail.

What I am trying to achieve is onkeyup of input, do something depending on what card type is caught:

```
 //on key up of input
 if (card == valid) 
   {
     if (card == visa)
      {
        //do something
      }
     else if (card == mastercard)
     {
        //do something
     }
       // repeat for rest of card types
   }
 else
   {
     //Just print an error
   }
```

I know it's fairly basic stuff, but can anybody help me with how to achieve?

```
 my HTML:
 <input type="text" id="cc_number" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developer of jQuery Credit Card Validator here.

jCCV binds the `keyup` event so you don’t need to do it. (actually it’s a little more complicated than that — all you need to know is that *every time* the value of the field changes, your callback function is executed).

```
$('#cc_number').validateCreditCard(function(result)
{
    // this will execute everytime the value of the `#cc_number` field changes

    if (result.length_valid && result.luhn_valid) {
        if (result.card_type.name == 'visa') {
            // do something
        } else if (result.card_type.name == 'mastercard') {
            // do something
        }       
        // repeat for rest of card types
    } else {
        // just print an error
    }
});
```

Comment: No problem! If you need any more help, you can contact me directly on Twitter @PawelDecowski. Glad to help!

Comment: Pawel, Please help on this post @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148771/jquery-validation-for-credit-card-limiting-to-visa-and-mastercard

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
$("#cc_number").on("keyup", function() {
    $(this).validateCreditCard(function(result) {
    alert('CC type: ' + result.card_type.name
      + '\nLength validation: ' + result.length_valid
      + '\nLuhn validation: ' + result.luhn_valid);
    });

    if (result.card_type.name) {
      if (result.card_type.name == visa)
      {
         //do something
      }
      else if (result.card_type.name == mastercard)
      {
         //do something
      }
      // repeat for rest of card types
   }
   else {
     //Just print an error
   }
});
```

Comment: Actually this is wrong. jCCV automatically binds the necessary events so the callback is executed whenever the value of the field changes. It will be optional in an upcoming version.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one by Stripe: https://github.com/stripe/jquery.payment

Much better.

Comment: This is a bit of an overkill since it’s a payment library and the validation functions are just helpers. I’m biased, though, as I’m the jQuery Credit Card Valildator developer ;)