# jQuery validation for credit card limiting to Visa and Mastercard

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using a jQuery validation plugin and an additional methods plugin. I am able to validate CC field. I have two questions.

1. How can I limit only Visa and Mastercard and display a message other than those two?
2. If I enter "0000000000000000" why does the validation plugin think it is
   a valid card?

I have used suggested caridtcard validator but geting an error.

[image]

Comment: Did you see [this](http://jquerycreditcardvalidator.com/)? To limit card types use { accept: ['visa', 'mastercard'] }.

Comment: Also you can write your own code, it's simple enough, first digit is responsible for card type, read about card number formats.

Comment: I have tried with CC validation plugin but geting a null objetc error. Please see attcghed image.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for late reply but I didn’t get a notification about the comment in the other thread! Can you post a link to a full-size image? I can barely read your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have cretaed a method as below.

```
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("vmcardsonly", function(value, element, param) {

if( value.charAt(0) == 4 || value.charAt(0) == 5){  
return true;
}else { 
return false;
}

  }, "Please enter a valid Visa or Master credit card number.");


  $('#MyForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin     

        rules: {

            ccNumber1: {
                required: true,             
                number: true,
                vmcardsonly: true,              
                minlength: 16,
                maxlength: 16

            }
        },


        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });
```